# RoR plugin for inviting friends

Tags: ruby-on-rails-plugins

could u suggest some socialnetworking plugins for inviting and adding friends,
for both registerd and unregistered users in website.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check this website http://jimneath.org/2008/04/25/building-a-social-network-site-in-rails/ for building a social networking site in rails using some plugins.

and check the stackoverflow question for some more information.

[Best Ruby on Rails social networking framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48320/best-ruby-on-rails-social-networking-framework)