# Is there a plugin like Elgg available for Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, social-networking, elgg

It seems Elgg is only for PHP, it has everything I need for my website. Is there something comparable other than CommunityEngine and LovdByLess? Are these the best alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Diaspora](https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora) was implemented in Ruby on Rails. They've got a lot of nice code there to fork or just even just read. The [Gemfile](https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora/blob/master/Gemfile) has a lot of useful suggestions. Mostly we roll our own. [Check out this related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48320/best-ruby-on-rails-social-networking-framework).